# Hash an XML file Using PHP

Tags: php, xml, hash, sdk

I have an XML file based on UBL 2.1 for ZATCA and I have the SDK file for developer to test their result and I have the hashed output and want to hash it in PHP, I tried to take the same XML content and hash it in PHP but the result is not the same, then after deep reading about XML and I tried to decompile the `CLASS` files of SDK to understand how do they hash it! then I found these classes but I am trying to understand it:

```
   public static String removeUnneededTags(final File file) {
        final List<String> pathsToBeRemoved = new ArrayList<String>();
        pathsToBeRemoved.add("//*[local-name()='Invoice']//*[local-name()='UBLExtensions']");
        pathsToBeRemoved.add("//*[local-name()='Invoice']//*[local-name()='Signature']");
        pathsToBeRemoved.add("//*[local-name()='Invoice']//*[local-name()='AdditionalDocumentReference']//*[text()= 'QR']/parent::*");
        final String cleanXml = removeElmentListByXpath(file, pathsToBeRemoved);
        final String removedNewlinesAndSpaces = cleanXml.replaceAll("[\\n\\t ]", "").replaceAll("\r", "");
        return removedNewlinesAndSpaces;
    }
```

what I understand is I have to remove `UBLExtensions` and `Signature` and `AdditionalDocumentReference related to QR` elements plust I have to remove all new lines and spaces? `\\n\\t` I already removed the elements and new lines and spaces to make the XML file as one line! that is what I understand, but still not get the same hashed output!

and I fund this class but didn't get the idea from it:

```
public static String removeElmentListByXpath(final File file, final List<String> paths) {
        try {
            final String result = IOUtils.toString((Reader)new FileReader(file));
            final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            final DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            final org.w3c.dom.Document doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
            final XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            final XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
            final TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            final Transformer transf = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transf.setOutputProperty("encoding", "UTF-8");
            transf.setOutputProperty("indent", "no");
            final XPath xPath;
            XPathExpression expr;
            final Object o;
            Node tobeDeleted;
            paths.forEach(path -> {
                try {
                    expr = xPath.compile(path);
                    tobeDeleted = (Node)expr.evaluate(o, XPathConstants.NODE);
                    tobeDeleted.getParentNode().removeChild(tobeDeleted);
                }
                catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                    Utils.log.warn(invokedynamic(makeConcatWithConstants:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;, e.getMessage()));
                }
                return;
            });
            final DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            final StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
            transf.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes");
            transf.transform(source, xmlOutput);
            return xmlOutput.getWriter().toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e2) {
            Utils.log.warn(invokedynamic(makeConcatWithConstants:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;, e2.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }
    }
```

my PH code to hash the content is :

```
$test_file = "tax_invoicenospaces.xml";
$test_file_read = file_get_contents($test_file);
  
$test_file_hash = hash_file("sha256", $test_file, false);

print("File Hash ($test_file_read): $test_file_hash");
```

If someone can explain it to me to help me to get the exact hashed.

Thanks,

Comment: Any idea for this case

Comment: how can we get a property node in xml (Get the properties tag only using the XPath) in 
PHP and then hash256 can you guide ?

Comment: Check this Typescript file, contain Zatca Signing solution: https://github.com/wes4m/zatca-xml-js/blob/e8ca61bedd3e0b09a2ff048c25a52b92f05bfe19/src/zatca/signing/index.ts

Answer (score 0):

The steps for hashing the XML file as mentioned by ZATCA documentations is

```
1. Remove the
<Invoice><ext:UBLExtensi
ons/> block
2. Remove the
<invoice><cac:Additional
DocumentReference/>
block where <cbc:ID/> =
QR
3. Remove the
<invoice><cac:Signature/>
block
4. Canonicalize the Invoice
using the C14N11
standard
5. Hash the resulting string
using SHA256 to a binary
object
6. Base64 encode the binary
object to generate the
digest value
```

If you dive deep in point 4 you will find some references in how to "Canonicalize" XML, I have found this [link](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/xmldsig-c14n.html) , try to go through the steps and it should work for you, keep in mind that it's not easy to do it so take your time to understand all the points.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, it should works:

```
$test_file = "tax_invoicenospaces.xml";
$test_file_read = file_get_contents($test_file);  
$test_file_hash = hash('sha256',$test_file,true) ;  
$Generated_Invoice_Hash =  base64_encode($test_file_hash);
echo $Generated_Invoice_Hash;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).